# Basics of waveform, how to define the zero point

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dft, wave

Audio is a sequence of waveforms which have peaks, troughs, 0, just like below.
[image: audio_waveform]

How to define the x axis (y = 0) in the picture, how to choose the 0 point in the waveform since there are so many points on the waveform?

Why not move the waveform above or below the x axis(y=0)?

This question seems a little stupid. But I still hope someone can help with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't produce a DC component with speech, so the line $y=0$ is defined by the speech signal having zero mean.

Comment: You are right Matt, but DC offset can be very often added by recording device itself.

Comment: @jojek: That's true but that would be an artefact and the DC component does not carry any information about the speech signal.

Comment: Could I use median instead? What consequences would it have?